# Zero knowledge proof to validate/invalidate a claim

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, cryptocurrency

Have a look at the Twitter conversation below in the screenshots.

1. @theveveshow asks if @trader1sz has sent ETH to the girl in question? @trader1sz responds that the girl in question has indeed sent him ETH. @theveveshow asks for proof.
2. @trader1sz asks if @theveveshow can prove @trader1sz is not his father?

How can we prove the above statements with zero-knowledge proof?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I doubt you can prove this is on-[topic](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)!

Comment: @fgrieu It is somewhat similar to verifying the identity of the prover. Here theveveshow has to prove his father's identity without revealing himself and without matching the DNA's of TradeSZ and Veve. I was thinking on the lines of the example: proving the red ball and green ball to a color blind person.

Answer (score 0):

trader1sz can just make a ZK-Proof he knows the discrete logarithm of the group element corresponding to the public key which received the coin in the relevant transaction.

[A simple interactive one](https://web.mat.upc.edu/jorge.villar/doc/notes/DataProt/zk.html#section2.2.1) makes sense, but
he can also use a non-interactive version of this protocol by applying [the Fiat-Shamir transform](https://web.mat.upc.edu/jorge.villar/doc/notes/DataProt/zk.html#section3.1).